# java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0

Tags: java, android

`Exception` to `Parcel`

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
```

i see coders are getting this in certain situations, but haven't seen it addressed for the 'google play activity' module in the hello world new project setup for the Android Studio, which i'm pretty much forced to use now that my last computer with Eclipse fried.

'blank activity' works on my phone device and emulator for the 'blank activity' hello world new activity setup, but not for the 'google play activity' hello world new activity setup. i've tried it with and without the various option boxes checked, like 'enable google play services'. i have added both

```
   uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" 

   uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

with no change to result. the application appears to load, then immediately crashes with 'Unfortunately, My Application has stopped'.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Google forgot to add this critical line to the manifest in the android studio new project 'google play activity' template:

```
meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id"
```

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, not Android Studio, so what should I set app_id to in strings.xml?